# Is it possible to read data from /map?

Tags: ros, navigation, mapping, ros-kinetic, subscribe

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello weveryone, I'm trying to read the data from the topic /map (in ROS Kinetic) but I don't know if I'm subscribing correctly.

I'm using the following code to count the number of gray pixels (unexplored pixels):

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <nav_msgs/MapMetaData.h>
#include <nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid.h>
#include "std_msgs/Header.h"
#include "nav_msgs/MapMetaData.h"

double Ngray = 0;

void mapCallback(const nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid::ConstPtr& msg){
  std_msgs::Header header = msg->header;
  nav_msgs::MapMetaData info = msg->info;
  nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid data = msg->data;
  ROS_INFO("Got map %d %d", info.width, info.height);
   for (unsigned int x = 0; x < info.width; x++)
    for (unsigned int y = 0; y < info.height; y++)
      if (data(x,y) == -1)
        Ngray++;
        ROS_INFO("Number of gray cells is: %e", Ngray);
      //map.Insert(Cell(x,y,info.width,msg->data[x+ info.width * y]));
  //nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid* newGrid = map.Grid();
  //newGrid->header = header;
  //newGrid->info = info;
  //map_pub.publish(*newGrid);
}
int main(int argc, char **argv){
  ros::init(argc, argv, "map_reader");
  ros::NodeHandle n;
  
  ros::Subscriber map_sub = n.subscribe("map",2000,mapCallback);
  
  ros::spin();
  return 0;
}
```

I'm having troubles with line 12. I'm sure I'm not writing it good, but I don't know how to.

Can anybody help me?

Thank you very much.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/287743/is-it-possible-to-read-data-from-/map?/) by [JaimeGJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/34515/jaimegj/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2018-04-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It would be really helpful to share the error message, but I guess that it is related to a type issue since the `msg->data` is an `int8[]` not a `nav_msgs::OccupancyGrid`.

Please refer to [OccupancyGrid message definition](http://docs.ros.org/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) and
see [this occupancygrid.cpp code](https://github.com/spauka/SLAM/blob/master/occupancygrid/occupancygrid.cpp)
The `mapCallback` function in it would be very useful as example and since you need to loop over cells note that you can use  `msg->data[x+ info.width * y]` and `not data(x,y)`

**Edit1:**

When looping over the width then height values,

`index=x+info.width*y` is a formula that will give you access to all the cells of the map column by column when you loop over x , y. for example for x=0 you will have `[0,1,...,info.height]`, for x=1 , `[info.height+1,...,2*info.height]` and so on ... finally we will get `[0,...,info.width*info.height]`.

This way to access cells is more useful if we have a special computation where we will make use of the current width and height (x,y) but in your case you can just use a simple loop since you just need to count the unexplored  cells,

```
for(int i=0; i<info.height*info.width; i++)
    {
        if(msg->data[i]==-1)
            Ngray++;
    }
```

Good luck!

---

Originally posted by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) with karma: 188 on 2018-04-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [JaimeGJ](https://answers.ros.org/users/34515/jaimegj/) on 2018-04-07**:
Thank you, Jasmin. The code I posted was based on that one that you said. What I want to do with the data from /map is to segment the map into zones explored and non-explored. So, if I want to read the value of one cell in the map, how could I write it?

**Comment by [Jasmin](https://answers.ros.org/users/28536/jasmin/) on 2018-04-08**:
Hey @JaimeGJ , I Edited my answer with some corrections and a more detailed explanation, please check it out and tell me if something is still unclear.